# Table header fixed not working with touch devices

Tags: css, scroll, fixed, touch-event, tableheader

I have Implemented a table middle of the page that table header fixed when scrolling. It works fine in all browsers but not in touch devices(mobile devices). Issue occurs because of fixed header apply when scroll finish in touch devices.

Any idea to remove juddering in touch devices(iphone, ipad)?

```js
var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
var $header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();        
    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedHeader.show();
    }
    else if (offset < tableOffset) {
        $fixedHeader.hide();
    }
});
```

```css
body { 
    height: 1000px; 
    font-size:20px;
}
#header-fixed { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px; 
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Here is some content</h1>
<table id="table-1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="header-fixed"></table>
```